# Sci-fi short-story collection for young readers - from the early seventies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I’m hoping someone can identify a short anthology of sci-fi stories I read as a fourth or fifth-grader, around 1971.  It was probably published specifically for younger readers.

I’m certain it included “The Last Command” by Keith Laumer and “Puppet Show” by Fredric Brown.  It’s probably where I read “Of Missing Persons” by Jack Finney as well.

This ***might*** have also been where I discovered Heinlein’s “The Roads Must Roll”, but I’m not sure about this one at all.

There were probably five or six other stories in the collection that I don’t remember or maybe never read - but as I remember it wasn’t a very large collection.  I don’t remember the cover either, although I have the feeling I might recognize it if I saw it.

Although the stories in it obviously pre-date the actual book, I’m certain the book would have be purchased new (probably from a drug-store book rack) in the early seventies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It could well be "[Tales of Time and Space](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?34403)", published  in 1969. It has all the stories you list (except for "The Roads Must Roll") and five others, in agreement with your memory. The time-frame is about right too. Does the cover jog your memory?

[image]

Comment: Agreed. I got that for a Christmas gift when it was first published.

Comment: Could the OP possibly have read the other edition with a different cover? http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?36345

Comment: My copy of that book has the green cover: http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/9/9c/TLSFTMNDSP0000.jpg

Comment: I was able to find the text from, or a description of, all but two of the stories listed for the book you've posted. I remember reading every single one of them.  I thought I might remember the cover too, but the one in your post doesn't ring any bells.  Maybe there were different editions. Still this almost certainly is the right book.  Thanks very much Clara!

Comment: @WeakyReader: Often you can find other editions easily via goodreads. This book indeed has [another edition with a very different cover](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1678924.Tales_Of_Time_And_Space). Does that ring a bell?

Comment: @User21820:  Thanks.  I did look up the other editions on Goodreads, but neither of them looked familiar.  I remembered the stories instantly when I saw them again - I had thought I might have the same reaction to the cover, but I did not.  I guess memory is a strange thing after all.